# Not receiving data from Cloud Firestore but there is the data

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a simples stream from Cloud Firestore. There is content inside of my Firestore data but the Stream doesn't seem to work.
This is how I build the Stream:

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('user_data').document('rCqMQ3oLjBLk6yg6P1oT').collection('Buttons').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError){
            return Container(color: Colors.red);
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            return GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: [
                CreateCard("ola"),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async{
                    print(snapshot.data);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        }
```

But it always enters in the ``ìf(!snapshot.hasData)```

Database image:
[image]

Comment: your code looks good; the `snapshot.data` should have List of `DocumentSnapshot` after stream gets into `active` state. have you tried checking the `connectionstate` instead of `hasData` boolean like sample code given in - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: I have created the connection state but, it enters in the waiting case. I printed the snapshot.data and received null

Comment: If it got stuck into waiting, might be network/connectivity issue.. you will get data `snapshot.data` only in `active or done` state..

Comment: But how am I having connection issue?

Comment: It's might be a case.. does the device has stable network connection?

Comment: Yes its all fine, I just don't get why this error is happening

Comment: Casually looked into this ref, might be useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111308/streambuilder-in-flutter-stuck-with-connectionstate-waiting-and-displays-only-th/61113958?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you set up your security rules? Sometimes I have this issue without getting an exception from firebase

Try to add this to the security rules for now.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Set up some rules later, this makes your database widely open.
https://medium.com/@khreniak/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e

Comment: security rules are not set yet.

Comment: thats might be the reason why it didnt load. Could you post them or try the ones I used in my updated post?

Comment: I will be trying to do what @MuthuTavamami suggested, if it doesn't work I will bring feedback

Comment: I'm still with the error, I will attempt your fix